# Azure DevOps - how to execute Pre and Post Deployment SQL scripts

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps release pipeline, How do I get our `Script.PreDeployment.sql` and `Script.PostDeployment.sql` files to execute during our SQL Server database deploy task?

In our release pipeline we have a Database Deployment phase, which has a SQL Server database deploy task. The tasks publishes our DACPAC file just fine. However I cannot figure out how to get the pre and post deployment scripts to execute.

Both of the scripts are included in the project, both have the appropriate BuildAction set to PreDeploy and PostDeploy. Yet in the logs of the dacpac deployment, there is no indication that the files were run - I have a bunch of `PRINT` statements in there.

Comment: If this post contained incomplete information, then please share why, else i'm not sure what it is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also working on the post deployment scrip by using SSDT approach, and for deployment I am using the **Azure SQL DacpacTask** task in my Azure Pipeline, so you just need to create the post deployment scripts as you can see this in image and save it, after you run the Azure build this will add it in the Azure Pipeline artifact ill automatically executed in above azure tasks under release pipeline. First it will executed the database deployment and after that it runs the post deployment script. It works for me .

[image]

Comment: Trying to understand how this resolved the issue, I have a pre deployment and post deployment script setup with the proper XML `PreDeploy` and `PostDeploy` tags, and yet, the Azure task is not running them.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **Command line task** to run those pre and post deployment SQL script using the `SQLCMD` tool.

The arguments to this its execution script are:

```
-S {database-server-name}.database.windows.net 

-U {username}@{database-server-name} 

-P {password} 

-d {database-name} 

-i {SQL file}
```

If you store the pre/postdeployment script in artifact, you can specify -i as like `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop/Script.PreDeployment.sql`.

Comment: is it possible to execute post/pre deployment scripts executed in Azure SQL Database deployment tasks, instead of adding other cmd tasks for execution
 ?

Answer (score 0):

Once Postdeployment script is added to the project, it will integrate with DacPac.
.sqlproj should have below PostDeploy Item group like -
`<ItemGroup> <PostDeploy Include="PostDeploymentScript path"/> </ItemGroup>`.
Sometime it does not update in .sqlproj and postdeployment does not work.
It should be added by default when postdeployment is added, just verify before publish.

[.sqlproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIuHZ.png)